# Finding extremas of a function with only using derivative of the function.

Tags: calculus, derivatives

$f'(x)=\dfrac{x^2(x-1)}{x+1}$ is given

Critical points are $0$ and $1$
Singular point is $-1$

$f''(x)=\dfrac{2x(x^2+x-1)}{(x+1)^2}$

So $-1$ is still not defined so it cannot be any extrema. Since function just diverges there.

For $x=1$ $f''(1)>0$ so it is local min.

About $x=-1$ is my assesment correct?

Comment: What does it mean to say that a function diverges at some point?

Comment: I mean at $x=-1$ it cannot have a real value, it is either undefined or limit goes there to infinity?

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not correct. Suppose, for instance, that $g(x)=\sqrt{\lvert x\rvert}$. Then it will be true that $g'$ and $g''$ are undefined at $0$. However, it is true that $g$ has a local minimum at $0$.

It is true, however, that your function $f$ does not have an extreme point at $-1$. This is so because, for some constant $K$,$$f(x)=2x-x^2+\frac13x^3-\log\left((x+1)^2\right)+K.$$

Comment: yes but is there a way to say that doesnot have an extreme just looking to f' without integrating?